# How to run Mercurial from MobaXterm

Tags: cygwin, mercurial

I'm using Windows 10 and have Cygwin and MobaXterm installed.
I need to use Mercurial.
It works fine from Cygwin but I want to run it from MobaXterm.
I just installed Mercurial plugin for MobaXterm and it claimed that it should run with Python 2.7
In my case I have both Python 3 and Python 2.
MobaXterm does not see Python 2.
Here's my environment:

```
 MobaXterm:
 ~/Desktop @ BOS-LTIRM181511 
| => which hg
hg is aliased to `/bin/hg'
hg is /bin/hg
hg is /drives/c/MobaXterm/slash/bin/hg
                                                                                                                                                                                                ✔
________________________________________________________________________________
| ~/Desktop @ BOS-LTIRM181511 
| => which python
python is aliased to `ToolNotIncluded python'
                                                                                                                                                                                                ✔
________________________________________________________________________________
| ~/Desktop @ BOS-LTIRM181511 
| => which python3
python3 is /bin/python3
python3 is /drives/c/MobaXterm/slash/bin/python3
                                                                                                                                                                                                ✔
________________________________________________________________________________
| ~/Desktop @ BOS-LTIRM181511 
| => /cygdrive/c/Python27/python --version
Python 2.7.15
                                                                                                                                                                                                ✔
________________________________________________________________________________
| ~/Desktop @ BOS-LTIRM181511 
| =>
----
Cygwin:
$  hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.0.2)
(see https://mercurial-scm.org for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2019 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

user@BOS-LTIRM181511 /usr/bin
$ which hg
hg is /usr/bin/hg
hg is /usr/bin/hg

user@BOS-LTIRM181511 /usr/bin
$ which python
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /cygdrive/c/Python27/python
python is /usr/bin/python

user@BOS-LTIRM181511 /usr/bin
$ which python3
-bash: type: python3: not found

user@BOS-LTIRM181511 /usr/bin
$ /cygdrive/c/Python27/python --version
Python 2.7.15

---
```

How could I fix it and make Mercurial run from MobaXterm?

Comment: what about using the Cygwin version of `hg` and `python2` ?

Comment: Cygwin version of hg works fine. I simply started to use only MobaXtrem instead of Cygwin because I like it more and don’t want to switch to Cygwin for hg. For now it’s the only option and I did it while it’s not convenient..

Comment: MobaXtrem is a terminal and Cygwin is a Posix enviroment. They are not exactly equivalent. If you are not planning to use Cygwin than I do no undertand the `cygwin` tag

Comment: I created an alias to python and now from MobaXterm I could run:
=> python --version
Python 2.7.15
But still I have the same error:
 => hg --version
bash: /bin/hg: /bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: cygwin links are not understood by windows application

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install Mercurial 5.7 on my PC and now I could use from MobaXterm

Comment: That's nice and all, but you fail to tell us the key bits of information necessary to make this into an answer, rather than a basic statement of resolution. If you included information on HOW you solved this problem, this would be an answer.

Comment: Actually this was not an answer per se. I failed to fix the root issue. I found the workaround that solved my issue. My goal was to make Mercurial to work in MobaXterm by using plugin. I achieved it by using Full Mercurial installation and now it works under MobaXterm as well.

Comment: @susik the same applies—you did not tell us the plugin you used, how you installed it, or how it helped. Please edit your post and include this information

Comment: Sorry not being clear. I installed it from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/.
It was a regular .msi install
After that Mercurial was in the path I was able to start it from command line.